# pageLength working only in firstpage - DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I just need to adjust few functions in my datatable (ref [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)) after or before ajax response. I tried to extend the page length to 30. Its working in first page only, Eg If I have 200 rows,

- first page shows "Showing **1 to 30** of 200 entries"
- second page shows "Showing **31 to 200** of 200 entries"
- third page shows "Showing **61 to 200** of 200 entries"

rest of the pages are same like this.

```
 success : function(data) { 

    var table=$('#datatable').DataTable()   // initializing datatable
    $('#datatable').dataTable().fnClearTable();  //clearing old data in every ajax response

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        table.row.add(  //adding rows
            [               
                data[i].name,
                data[i].phone
            ])
            .draw();
    }

    table.destroy()  // destroy existing datatable and appending following objects

    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtlip', 
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel','print', 'colvis' ], 
        columns: [  
            {name: 'name', title: 'Name'},      // Renaming Header
            {name: 'phone', title: 'Phone'}     
        ],
        rowsGroup: [        // Using rowspan / grouping     
            'name:name',
            'phone:name'          
        ],
        pageLength: '30' //page length

        })

    }   //end of success()
```

If I don't destroy existing table, it shows an error message *"cannot reinitialise datatable"*. I think the problem with `table.destroy()`. **If I comment `pageLength: '30'`, its working fine as default(10 records per page)**

Is there any way to add objects without destroying? or adding these objects while creating rows/ initializing datatable? Or any way to soleve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`pageLength: 30` //page length should be an integer :D :D